# Android - RelativeLayout - position a checkbox on the center of an image

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I would like to know how can I center a checkbox to an image on my `RelativeLayout` view - there is no property like this..

Here's my code:

http://pastebin.com/tGAxju3Z

Please notice: the image is bigger then the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FrameLayout` for the following

```
<FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/image1"
>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/image2" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to position chechbox in center of the image?

Comment: Yes... The image is onLeftOf to the RelativeLayout, and I want the checkBox to be Vertical Centered to RelativeLayout but also horizontal centered within the image.., I dont want to add another RelativeLayout inside the RelativeLayout (which will be easy, but not performance wise...)

Comment: you also do not need to use imageview...simply set that image to the background of the framelayout

Comment: I didn't want to use nested layout but there seems to be no other way.. I will use your code - thanks..

Comment: @dinbrca:if you find this useful just upvote or accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a relative layout, it will be better if you take a linearlayout with its background as an image and then place the checkbox on the linearlayout...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the layout_height of CheckBox is the same as the layout_height of your ImageView, same for the layout_width, and add the gravity. Be sure the ImageView and Checkbox are in another layout (with layout_width and layout_height set to wrap_content), than the TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:padding="5dp" 
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:background="#e2e2e2"
 >
     <ImageView 
         android:contentDescription="Icon" 
         android:layout_width="74dp"
         android:layout_height="64dp"
         android:id="@+id/imgThumbnail"
         android:scaleType="centerInside" 
     />

     <CheckBox 
         android:id="@+id/chkEdit" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:gravity="center" 
         android:visibility="visible" 
     />
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView />
```

Tip: Add android:background="#FF0000" (=RED) and android:background="#00FF00" (=GREEN) to the different widgets, so you can exactly see what is covered by the item.